# Definition of prime ideals: inclusive or exclusive "or"? with example

Tags: abstract-algebra

The definition I'm working with:
Let $R$ be a ring and $P$ be an ideal. Then for any $a,b\in R$, $ab\in P\implies a\in P$ or $b\in P$. We call $P$ a *prime ideal*.

I'm guess that the "or" here is exclusive because if it was inclusive, then there would be a contradiction in the case of $R=\mathbb{Z}$. I'm wondering is there a more abstract example of a prime ideal that uses the inclusive "or"?

Edit: the contradiction is that assume $(6)$ is a prime ideal. But $2,3 \notin (6)$ so $(6)$ is not prime.

Comment: Can you tell us which contradiction you found?

Comment: Why can't a prime  which divides $ab$ divide both factors?

Comment: "*If it was inclusive then there would be a contradiction in the case of $R=\Bbb Z$*"  How so?  $81$ is among the "*multiples of three*"... the prime ideal generated by the *prime* $3$.  Here, we indeed have that $81=3\cdot 27$ and both $3$ and $27$ are also among the *multiples of three*, not just one of them.

Comment: @S.Farr, I was thinking about how $(6)$ is not a prime ideal but $2, 3\notin (6)$. So I'd say "suppose (6) is prime" and get a contradiction. Unless I'm thinking about it in the wrong way?

Comment: @Bernard, if $p$ is prime and $p|a and p|b$ assuming not both $a=1, b=1$ then $p$ is not prime.

Comment: But $(6)$ is not prime, so it's all good! The negation of the statement $ab\in P \Rightarrow a\in P\, \vee \,b\in P$ is indeed $a\not \in P \wedge b\not \in P \Rightarrow ab\not \in P$, but this only has to hold if $P$ is indeed prime.

Comment: @JMoravitz, hmm. I guess I was thinking of $(6)$ when I wrote that sentence. So to better understand your example, we have that $(3)$ is a prime ideal that where $3*27=81\in (3)$ and I agree that both $27$ and $3$ are in $P$!! Ah thank you for this lovely example :)

Comment: It is always worth having some favorite every-day play examples to understand some of these abstract concepts.  Ideals in $\Bbb Z$ are of the form "*the set of multiples of $n$*" and the *prime* ideals are of the form "*the set of multiples of $p$*" with $p$ prime.

Comment: @cheeseboardqueen: for instance $3\mid 15\times6$, yet $3\mid 15$ *and* $3\mid 6$. Are you sure $3$ isn't prime?

Comment: @Bernard,  surely 3 is prime! I guess I was putting too many assumptions onto $a$ and $b$. I guess $p|ab\implies ab=ab'p$ where $b=b'p$. This gives that $p|b$. I could have done the same with $a$.

Comment: I think that maybe you were confusing with the statement of Euclid's lemma.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The 'or' cannot be exclusive. Suppose $ab\in P$ implied $a\in P$ or $b\in P$ but not both for any $a,b\in R$. Since $P$ is nonempty by definition, there exists some $a\in P$. Then $a*a\notin P$, since '$a\in P$ and $a\in P$'. But $P$ is closed under multiplication, by definition of an ideal, so $a*a\in P$. This is a contradiction, so it is impossible for an ideal to satisfy the prime ideal definition with the exclusive 'or'.

By the way, the unmodified 'or' is always* used in the inclusive sense in mathematical writing; if exclusive 'or' is intended, the author must assert that.

(*At least, that is the standard accepted meaning.)

Comment: Thank you for this clarification! I always wondered what would happen if an exclusive "or" is needed in math.

Comment: Please strive not to add more dupe answers to dupes of FAQs, cf. site policy [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/33508/242).

Answer (score 3):

The "or" is inclusive. For example, in $\mathbb{Z}$, the ideal $(2)$ is a prime ideal. And $2*2 = 4 \in (2)$, and both $2$ and $2$ are in $(2)$.

Comment: Please strive not to add more dupe answers to dupes of FAQs, cf. site policy [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/33508/242).